# Find the percentage left comparing two Durations

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two Durations and I would like to find the percentage left comparing the total duration and the duration left.

```
Total Duration - 1:00:00.000000
Duration Left - 0:15:00.000000
```

I had hoped some sort of comparison or division option, but they don't seem to exists. I would like to get a result like 25% time left.

How can I do this in Dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert `Duration` to `seconds` or `microseconds` the one you prefer, then do the percentage operation.

To remove the decimal points you can use `.toInt()`,`.truncate()`, or `.floor()`
.

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  Duration total = Duration(hours: 1);
  Duration left = Duration(minutes: 15);

  final percentage = (left.inSeconds / total.inSeconds * 100).truncate();
  print("$percentage%");
}
```

Comment: Using `.toInt()`, `.truncate()`, or `.floor()` would be clearer/more idiomatic than `~/ 1`.